# writing Insert statement in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, winforms, stored-procedures

I have 2 sql table

```
[dbo].[Contract]
[ContractID] pk,.....other column

[dbo].[Installment] //this table has composite primary key
[ContractID] pk n fk // it is primary and foreign key
[installmentNum] pk, // contractID and installmentnum both are the primary keys
```

A ContractID has 6 or 12 installments for this i used installmentNum column for insertion through a winform i write this stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertUpdateInstallment]
@ContractID int = 0,
@InstallmentNumber int = 0,
@month varchar(10),
@installment money = 0.00,
@commission money = 0.00,
@iupdate int = 0
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON 
SET XACT_ABORT ON  
BEGIN TRAN
 if @ContractID<>0 and @iupdate=0 //i'm confused here
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Installment] 
VALUES(@InstallmentNumber,@month,@installment,@commission)
END
if @ContractID <>0 and @month is not null and @iupdate=1
BEGIN
UPDATE [dbo].[Installment] 
SET 
[ContractID] = @ContractID,
[InstallmentNumber] = @InstallmentNumber,
[currentMonth] = @month,
[installment] = @installment,
[commission] = @commission
WHERE [ContractID] = @ContractID and [currentMonth] = @month
END
Commit
```

second for reading installments one by one of selected contract i'm trying to write this stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spReadInstallment]
@ContractID int = 0
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON 
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN tran
if @ContractID<>0
begin tran
BEGIN
SELECT     ContractID, InstallmentNumber, currentMonth, installment, commission
FROM         Installment
WHERE     (ContractID = @contractid) // have doubt about the select statement?
END
commit
```

I have confusion About the SELECT statement of the spReadInstallment and insert statment of the spInsertUpdateInstallment I'm beginer and can't understand the mistake behind kindly guide me

Comment: What is the "mistake" you are experiencing? What trouble are you having? Please be more specific.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you appear to be leaving a hanging transaction in spReadInstallment. You have two begin trans, but only one commit. I'm not sure if you really need the transactions anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `if @ContractID<>0 and @iupdate=0 //i'm confused here`

Your first stored procedure is performing an *upsert* (update or insert) - it will insert or update a table depending on the arguments given for the PK parameters:  `@ContractID` and `@iupdate`

When those two both have value `0`, then the stored proc will perform an insert. Otherwise, it'll perform an update to the table.

**Analyse whether you really need all those default values on your parameters here.**

Your second stored procedure, have no doubts. Rewrite it like this without the default value `0` on the `@ContractID`, and without the unnecessary multiple hanging transactions on a SELECT operation:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spReadInstallment]
@ContractID int
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT    ContractID, InstallmentNumber, currentMonth, installment, commission
FROM      Installment
WHERE     ContractID = @contractid;
```